# Robolectric Application instance is always null

Tags: android, robolectric

I tried running robolectric library with versions 3.3.2 and 3.4-rc3. My code internally tries to fetch a singleton instance of the application. But when my test runs, the application instance retrieved is always null. It works fine with robolectric 3.1.2. I wanted to upgrade as I wanted to use powermocks in the test. There were similar questions in stackoverflow. But it did not help me. Please advise. Following is my test code. I tried running with PowerMockRunnerDelegator as shown here. Also, tried with the normal RobolectricTestRunner as the Runner. Both the approaches did not work.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21, application = 
TestApplication.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({ "org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", 
"android.*"})
   @PrepareForTest({MockActor.class})
    public class MyTest {
     @Mock
     private MockActor mockActorInstance;

     @Rule
     public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
       initMocks(this);
       PowerMockito.mockStatic(MockActor.class);
       whenNew(MockActor.class).withAnyArguments()
           .thenReturn(mockActorInstance);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldTriggerCall() {
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();

        startFragment(myFragment);
        myFragment.doAction();
        verify(mockActorInstance).invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom ShadowApplication and stub your static getApplication method there. Hopefully this https://medium.com/@chuangx/get-around-with-app-getapplication-in-robolectric-4b88d559fca5 helps